# Javascript: object with array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, object

I'm fighting with some JSON and met situation similar to something below:

```js
let build = '{"books": [{"title":"Something", "pages": 154, "illustrations":false},{"title":"Blabla", "pages": 356, "illustrations":true},{"title":"nope", "pages": 700, "illustrations":false}] }'

let books = JSON.parse(build);
console.log(books)
```

I can't find a way to reach data inside this 'Book' object. Could you give me some hint?

Answer (score 0):

What you provided seems to work, then you can access data inside it, just as you would to in a literal object in javascript:

```js
let build = '{"books": [{"title":"Something", "pages": 154, "illustrations":false},{"title":"Blabla", "pages": 356, "illustrations":true},{"title":"nope", "pages": 700, "illustrations":false}] }'

let data = JSON.parse(build);
console.log(data.books[0].title)
```

I think you got confused by the variable name you chose: `JSON.parse` will not go to the `books` key by itself, because there could be other keys

Answer (score 0):

```
books.books[0]
```

should show the

```
next : {title: 'Something', pages: 154, illustrations: false}
```

or if you prefer you can iterate in the next way

```
books.books.forEach (element => console.log(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.` operator to access properties, and the array access operator `[]` or some kind of iteration to access the array elements.

```js
const build = '{"books": [{"title":"Something", "pages": 154, "illustrations":false},{"title":"Blabla", "pages": 356, "illustrations":true},{"title":"nope", "pages": 700, "illustrations":false}] }'

// convert JSON to object
const data = JSON.parse(build);
// Pull out the 'books' property from the root level object
const books = data.books;
// see what it looks like
console.log(books);

// Define a function that will iterate the books and print some info about the book
const printAllTitles = (books) => {
  books.forEach(book => {
    console.log(`${book.title} is ${book.pages} pages long`)
  })
}

// Call that function
printAllTitles(books);
```